# int-http:outbound-gateway HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring, spring-integration, rest-client, spring-rest

We have used **int-http:outbound-gateway**

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="userDataRequest"
                           id="outboundUserDetailsGateway" url-expression="url"
                           http-method="GET" expected-response-type="com.xxx.UserResponse">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

The GET request that we are hitting from outbound gateway is working fine. We have validated it through various rest clients/curl.

**Flow overview**

User Hit some post request(Inbound request). That request is retrieve by int-http:inbound-gateway. It order to get some details our system hits one GET(Outbound request) request that is mentioned above to some other system.

**Problem**
When the Inbound request(POST) is done by curl/jmeter/Advance rest client it is working fine however, If that request is from postman/boomerang, Then it is showing

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3f0a204c; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3f0a204c; line: 1, column: 2]

We are getting this error when system hits Outbound request (GET) request.

Comment: What is a question though? Why Jackson disallow CTRL-CHAR as white space ?

Comment: Why it is behaving differently with different origins. Like with CURL It is Okay where in with Restclient like postman. It is showing mentioned error. I am expecting thoughts, what is the possible reasons for the discrepancy in the execution behaviour.

Comment: CURL and Java uses different mechanisms to read JSON. More over CURL doesn't parse JSON to particular object like it happens in your case with Jackson

Comment: did any one found the solution ?

Comment: @UditKumawat Added my answer which works for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we were including application/json in gzip at Service side Nginx. We just excluded application/json from gzip and It works for us.